# thread.sleep doesnt work properly on my device

Tags: android

I built an app and put it on Google Play. I downloaded the app both on my LG K10 and on my LG G3. The function `Thread.sleep()` works fine on my LG K10 (I set the `Thread.sleep()` to 50 mili-seconds) but for some reason the function doesnt work well on my LG G3, the app works very slowly and it the function updates very slowly (it takes more time than 50ms).

Comment: I think that it works correctly on your G3. Since you shouldn't `sleep` the UI thread. It will lead to lags, as you see on your G3.

Comment: Add your code with the sleep part.

Comment: is there another method of updating the UI?

Comment: 'it takes more time than 50ms'. Where does it say it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use runOnUiThread() from a non UI thread to update the UI.That method uses a handler internally if you are not currently on the UI thread so  using your own handler will not be more efficient. If you are already on the 
UI thread then the runnable will be executed immediately.

Example code:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // to do      
           }       
      });
```